# WP7 Flashlight Application Error

Tags: windows-phone-7, flashlight

In this application there are two buttons to open and close camera flashlight.
I am using this code but i get an error.

```
using Microsoft.Devices;

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    PhotoCamera cam = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.FrontFacing); 

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.On;  
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.Off;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=You cannot use this instance until it is fully initialized. You can initialize by passing this Camera object to VideoBrush.SetSource(...)

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is not so easy...
The flash on the phone can be accessed via the PhotoCamera object. So the first thing I tried was to turn on the flash this way.To use the photo camera you need two objects the PhotoCamera and the VideoBrush.

```
private PhotoCamera _photoCamera;
private VideoBrush _videoBrush;

// Check to see if the camera is available on the device.
if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary))
{
    // Use standard camera on back of device.
    _photoCamera = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);

    // Event is fired when the PhotoCamera object has been initialized.
    _photoCamera.Initialized += PhotoCamera_Initialized;

    // Add the photo camera to the video source
    _videoBrush = new VideoBrush();
    _videoBrush.SetSource(_photoCamera);
}

private void PhotoCamera_Initialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if flash mode is supported on the device.
    if (_photoCamera.IsFlashModeSupported(FlashMode.On))
    {
        // Turn the flash on.
        _photoCamera.FlashMode = FlashMode.On;
        _photoCamera.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: what error ? this does not contains all the code but the idea is here : you have to use PhotoCamera & VideoBrush .

Comment: I've added the photo camera to the video source but i am keep getting the same error.